# Lubuntu 18.04 lxde indicator applet and applications are not working

Tags: lubuntu, indicator, lxde, indicator-sound, lxpanel

I am sort of new lubuntu, I have installed redshift and kde-connect which was perfectly indicated in indicator applet. 
After restarting my laptop indicator applet and application of it started not working (sound indicator included)
does anyone has an idea how to fix it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem of sound indicator by using `sudo apt-get install indicator-sound-gtk2` then readding the indicator applet and adding from preferences.

but Unfortunately it is not working for indicator applications

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem on one of my Lubuntu installations. Battery indicator and sometimes sound indicator work, but I was missing indicators for items like Redshift, Chrome apps, Wi-fi, etc. Basically anything that should be shown under "Indicator applets".

I discovered that using Task Manager to quit ("term" rather than stop or kill) the service called *indicator-application-service* would get all the indicators working again. *Indicator-application-service* will automatically restart, but it's not a problem after that. Weird but works for me.

I would add a terminal command to do this to the LXDE auto-start, but I'm not sure of which command to use. Anyone else know?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command:

```
pkill indicator-appli
```

You can add it to the LXSession configuration -> Autostart.
Press the "plus" - sign, insert the command, that's it.

When executed, the applet-icons will appear in the lower-right panel-bar.
(Lubuntu 18.04)